# How to check whether a file (from the list of file names) exist or not in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, filenames, directory

I have a list of file names like

```
22.75_87.dat
22.75_87.25.dat
22.75_87.5.dat
22.75_87.75.dat
23_86.dat
23_86.25.dat
23_86.5.dat
23_86.75.dat
23_87.dat
23_87.25.dat
23_87.5.dat
23_87.75.dat
23.25_86.dat
23.25_86.25.dat
23.25_86.5.dat
23.25_86.75.dat
23.25_87.dat
23.25_87.25.dat
23.25_87.5.dat
```

and so on.

Out of these file names I only few files exist. I need to make folders exactly same as the exisitng file names only. How to do this?

I can generate the filenames, but have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: so what are you expecting as output?

Comment: You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python

Comment: @grael thanks I did it.